# altering a print statement

Tags: python, list, printing

i'm having trouble finding the correct output. Lets say i'm given two lists, list A and list B.

```
list A = [1,2,3]
list B = [2,3,4]
```

I want to print out a statement like the following..

```
Solution A : 1 2 3
Solution B : 2 3 4
```

What I have done so far is...

```
    A = config.mList
    B = config.sList
    return 'Solution A: %s \nSolution B: %s' %(A, B)
```

This just prints out

```
Solution A: ['17', '4', '8', '11'] 
Solution B: ['9', '18', '13']
```

Comment: How about using " ".joiin(A)?

Answer (score 3):

In Python 2.x:

```
print 'Solution A:', ' '.join(A)
```

In Python 3.x:

```
print('Solution A:', *A)
```

Note that the `print` function in Python 3.x automatically calls `str` on the objects that it's provided. Whereby `' '.join` requires the objects to already be strings, so to make sure of that use:

```
print ' '.join([str(el) for el in A])
```

Or:

```
print ' '.join(map(str, A))
```

Comment: @alko possibly - see my comment to iCodez answer

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`str.join`](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) and [`str.format`](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/stdtypes.html#str.format):

```
>>> A = ['1','2','3']
>>> B = ['2','3','4']
>>> print "Solution A : {}\nSolution B : {}".format(" ".join(A), " ".join(B))
Solution A : 1 2 3
Solution B : 2 3 4
>>>
```

---

Note however that the items in the lists *must* be strings before you use `str.join`.  In your sample, you gave lists of integers.  So, if you have those, you can do this:

```
>>> A = [1,2,3]
>>> B = [2,3,4]
>>> print "Solution A : {}\nSolution B : {}".format(" ".join(map(str, A)), " ".join(map(str, B)))
Solution A : 1 2 3
Solution B : 2 3 4
>>>
```

Here is a reference on [`map`](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html#map).

Comment: I was wondering if they needed to `str`ify them or not... the current output and example input seem to contradict each other in regards to type

Comment: Thank you @iCodez for the code. I have never used {} and format before. But is format used to place the objects inside of the {}?

Comment: @user2933041 - Yes, that is exactly what is going on.  For example, `"{}{}{}".format(1, 2, 3)` will yield `"123"`.

Comment: @JonClements - Eh, I don't know for sure either.  I'll give him both answers.

Answer (score 0):

Use the join function to convert your lists into strings and then format them.

```
' '.join(A) #  "1 2 3"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set up a little function to format the items to a text string, you'll avoid a repeat when you format them:

```
def textlist(mylist):
    return ' '.join(map(str, mylist))

print "Solution A: {0} \nSolution B: {1}".format(textlist(A), textlist(B))
```

Comment: Note: in Python 2.7+, you can omit the numbers inside the curly braces.